# NVarchar2 fields inserted as blank/NULL while Importing data from SQL Server to Oracle over dblink

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm currently importing data from a SQL Server database into an Oracle 11g one and I'm encountering some strange behavior when importing nvarchar2 columns. The charset on the SQL Server db is Unicode (UTF-8), while on Oracle's side it is not (WE8ISO8859P1).

Whenever i try to import SQL Server nvarchar2 values, Oracle inserts them as blank strings. Trying this on a different IDE, the show up as NULL. Whatever I do, the text is not imported.

I've had success using the `dbms_hs_passthrough` package, yet this seems overkill for such a simple insert/select task.

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** If i perform a SELECT on the remote table I can see the text values just fine. CTAS also works as expected. I can only replicate the erroneous behavior when i run the package.

**EDIT 2:** I've narrowed this problem down to a possible bug in the MERGE statement in Oracle with data from SQL Server over DBLink. I solved this problem by performing separate INSERT/UPDATE DML statements.

Comment: What package are you running? What exact thing are you doing here? Can you provide a minimal example that demonstrates your issue?

Comment: @Ben It's a simple package i developed. I'm using a MERGE statement and that seems to be the root cause. See my EDIT.